# How do I enable the radio buttons after the checkbox is checked?

Tags: javascript, html, web

Basically, I have a checkbox with 2 radio buttons (disabled by default), I want to enable them when the checkbox is checked. How do I do this with JavaScript?

Comment: is this disabled using a css class ?

Comment: What you have tried yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one with javascript

```js
function changeThis(sender) { 
  if(document.getElementById('chkbx').checked){
    document.getElementById("first").removeAttribute('disabled');
    document.getElementById("second").removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
  else{
    document.getElementById("first").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("second").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="chkbx" onchange="changeThis(this)" />
<input type="radio" name="receipt" id="first" disabled />
<input type="radio" name="receipt" id="second" disabled />
```

Comment: You are forcing the checkbox state to be true because you are using assign `=` instead of comparison `==`. Otherwise, you can simply check the truthy value of the checked prop, i.e. `if (chbx.cehcked)`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the ternary operator:

```js
function myFunction() {
document.getElementById('checkBox').checked ?
(
document.getElementById("1").disabled = false,
document.getElementById("2").disabled = false
):(
document.getElementById("1").disabled = true,
document.getElementById("2").disabled = true
)
;
    
}
```

```html
CheckBox<input type="checkbox" id="checkBox" onchange="myFunction(this)" />
<br>
Radio 1<input type="radio"  id="1" disabled />
<br>
Radio 2<input type="radio"  id="2" disabled />
```

Answer (score -1):

Enable/disable Radio Button based on checked status of checkbox.

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function () {
     if($('#myCheck').is(':checked')) {
        $('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', false);
     }
    else{
        $('input[type=radio]').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="myCheck">Click to Enable Disable <br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male" disabled="disabled">Male<br>
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female" disabled="disabled">Female<br>
```

Comment: Do not assume that OP wants to use jQuery, even though I understand that it is an easy solution. You wouldn't want to load an **entire** JS library just for that simple function.

Answer (score -1):

In [jQuery](http://jquery.com):

```
$("#mycheckbox").change(function(){
    if($(this).checked)
        $("#myradiobutton").disabled(false);
});
```

Note that `#mycheckbox` and `#myradiobutton` are the ids of tbe DOM elements.

Comment: Do not assume that OP wants to use jQuery, even though I understand that it is an easy solution. You wouldn't want to load an **entire** JS library just for that simple function.